# Check if two objects are equal when they have floating point values?

Tags: javascript, binary, floating-point, equality

Writing some test cases for my Javascript program that deals with binary and right now I'm just using stringify to check if the value and expected values are equal:

```
JSON.stringify(val) === JSON.stringify(expected)
```

This works fine except for when I have floating point values. This is what happens:

```
Given Value:    [10,20,30,32.400001525878906,{"test":3,"asdf":23}]
Expected Value: [10,20,30,32.4,{"test":3,"asdf":23}]

Test Failed!
```

So I guess I can't use stringify anymore to check if my two objects/arrays are equal. What's a good way to check if two potentially deeply nested objects/arrays are equal while also taking in to account floating point values? That is, two floating point values should be considered equal if they are 99.99% the same or whatever.

Comment: You need to write a recursive equivalence tester. And when it gets to a floating point number, it needs to compare them with tolerance, rather than `==`.

Comment: Comparing Objects using JSON.stringify is not a good idea as there is no guarantee of order, so two objects may have identical properties and values but evaluate to not "equal". You need to loop over the properties and values, there are [*many, many questions about that already*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+compare+objects).

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to test each element in the array in order, and you'll need to do it recursively for objects. This is typically known as a deep comparison or deep equality. You should be able to do this using a recursive function that checks the type(s) of the comparands.

When comparing floating point values, you'll want to use a tolerance. You do this by taking the absolute value of subtracting the two numbers from each other, and then comparing that to either a fixed tolerance value of your choosing, or a small number known as an epsilon.

In JavaScript, the machine epsilon is available as [Number.EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON), and is defined to be the difference between 1 and the smallest number that is greater than 1 **and** can be represented as a `Number`. Similar constants are available in most languages and are typically used for tolerance-based comparisons.

Tolerance-based comparison turns floating point comparisons from simple equality into a subtract and compare. If you'd normally write

```
if (a === b) { ... }
```

you'd write that using the absolute value and a `tolerance` to eliminate floating point weirdness:

```
var tolerance = Number.EPSILON;
if (Math.abs(a - b) < tolerance) { ... }
```

If the difference between `a` and `b` is smaller than `tolerance`, you treat them as equal.

For a more nuanced (but possibly overkill for your case) approach, see [The Floating Point Guide's section on comparison](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). The implementation presented there is in Java, but is likely portable to JavaScript without much effort.

Comment: I think that Number.EPSILON is a little too small to be used. I think it should be scaled by a factor depending on the actual numbers (or their difference). So rather large numbers are not compared to differ by the ulp of 1.0

Comment: Yeah, I tried to touch on that here, but was not necessarily successful. :) Open to suggestions on how to better word the answer.